# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to implement master and slave in 2 different laptops using apache spark, however the worker is not connecting to the master, even though it is on the same network and the following error shows up..... please do help

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:313)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.212.43:7077
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:288)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:218)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:230)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /192.168.212.43:7077
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)